# Execute completeAjax only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to fire a function on completion of an already running ajax on the page. The function I want to update will update wishlist item counter and the function which is previously running saves item in wishlist.

The problem is (what I've figured out) - after making (initializing) ajax request, while waiting for success msg, the function again executes itself.

Bottom line, I want ajaxComplete function part to run only once ever. Please point me in right direction

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {

    var token = false;

    jQuery( '.add_to_wishlist' ).on( 'click', function() {

            if( token == false ) {

                jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function() {

                    console.log('Entered Click!');

                    token = true;

                    jQuery.ajax({

                        url: wishajax.ajax_url,
                        data: {
                            action: 'vg_inject_wish',
                        },
                        success: function( response ) {

                            console.log('Entered Success!');

                            jQuery( '.wishlist-container' ).html( response );

                            console.log('After Success!');

                            token = true;

                        }

                    }); 

                });

            }
    });

});
```

Comment: what about `complete: function( response ) {..` just before `success` Refer https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Comment: @vajrasar - define "ever"

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery(document).ajaxComplete` is an independent `event`. Why are you combining it inside `click` event and writing again `jQuery.ajax` inside it? Separate the concerns as below:

```
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    token = true;//If you need this only in success then no need to put it here as this 
    //will get executed irrespective of ajax result
});

jQuery( '.add_to_wishlist' ).on( 'click', function() {
    if( token == false ) {
          jQuery.ajax({
                 url: wishajax.ajax_url,
                 data: {
                      action: 'vg_inject_wish',
                 },
                 success: function( response ) {
                      console.log('Entered Success!');
                      jQuery( '.wishlist-container' ).html( response );
                      console.log('After Success!');
                      token = true;
                 }
           }); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you to

```
    function once(fn, context) { 
    var result;

    return function() { 
        if(fn) {
            result = fn.apply(context || this, arguments);
            fn = null;
        }

        return result;
    };
}

// Usage
var canOnlyFireOnce = once(function() {
    console.log('Fired!');
});

canOnlyFireOnce(); // "Fired!"
canOnlyFireOnce(); // nada
```

taken from the [blog of David Walsh](http://davidwalsh.name/essential-javascript-functions).